# cypher query using http/bolt into Neo4j hangs Java thread

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Neo4j 3.5.14 Enterprise (cypher over http/bolt). I'm seeing an issue where randomly a cypher query would be stuck never to be back again which takes out a worker thread. Eventually, if the service is not redeployed, all worker threads would be stuck and the service is no longer doing its job.

I tried using `apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed` but that appears to cause my queries to not return until the time limit is over (20000 ms in this case) even though in some cases it can return faster than that. I'm actually not sure that `runTimeboxed` would work because I believe it is actually stuck forever which might not respond to time limit anyway depending on how that's implemented.

My question is - how would you end a runaway query like that? Any tricks?

Comment: It would help to know what kind of errors (if any) you see in the debug logs for such queries, as well as to know what's going on in a listTransactions() call.

Comment: Thanks. I will try a listTransactions() when it happens again. It only happens in our prod environment and I'm not able to access those logs easily. It actually only 1 query but for different Neo4j instances. We have one instance per customer. And that 1 query works over and over again... until it gets stuck!